# database_cleaner, factory_girl, and multiple databases - Configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, multiple-databases

Currently trying test multiple db's using capybara/rspec/factory girl, though having issues with my DB clearing.

Query error:

```
': Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '1503' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `users`
```

Facilities_spec.rb

```
feature "User with facilities" do
  @current_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_facility)   
  scenario 'A user can perform a walk-through', :js => true do
    login_as
    visit '/'
    expect(page).to have_text "Our records indicate that you have access to 1 facilities:"
    ...
  end

  @current_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_facility)   
  scenario 'The quick-form requires first_name, last_name, and dob', :js => true do
    login_as
    visit '/'
    expect(page).to have_text "Our records indicate that you have access to 1 facilities:"
    ...
  end
end
```

rails_helper.rb

```
cleaner = DatabaseCleaner[:active_record,{:connection => :emp_portal_test}]
rt_cleaner = DatabaseCleaner[:active_record, {connection: :test_rt_treats}]

RSpec.configure do |config|
 config.include Capybara::DSL
 config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

 config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

 config.before(:suite) do 
   cleaner.strategy = :truncation
   rt_cleaner.strategy = :truncation     
 end

 config.before(:each) do 
   cleaner.strategy = :truncation
   rt_cleaner.strategy = :truncation
   cleaner.start
   rt_cleaner.start
 end

config.before(:each, :js => true) do
  cleaner.strategy = :truncation
  rt_cleaner.strategy = :truncation
end

config.after(:each) do 
  cleaner.clean
  rt_cleaner.clean   
end
```

user_factory.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :user do
  id 33065
  first_name "Andrew"
  last_name  "Larson"
  select_id "al44096"
    factory :user_with_facility do
      after(:create) do |user|
        user.facility_assignments << create(:facility)
      end
    end
  end

factory :facility do
    id 1550
    ref_select_id 1550
    status -1
    name "St. Paul's Home & Apartments"
    name_internal "St Paul's Home"
    dept_id "R51"
    ...
end
```

When I create a new patient within this test environment, it is wiped before my next use, though I cannot use my same current_user throughout my code.

Comment: How are you managing the multiple database connections? Are you using a gem for that or doing manually?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by 'manage'.  I have cleaner = DatabaseCleaner[:active_record,{:connection => :emp_portal_test}]
rt_cleaner = DatabaseCleaner[:active_record, {connection: :test_rt_treats}] each establishing a connection to the DB in order to perform the clean tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a few pieces...

1. One of my databases' tables did not have an auto-increment feature for it's id which was an issue, so I added auto increment to the table via ...

   ```
   ALTER TABLE document MODIFY COLUMN document_id INT auto_increment
   ```
2. Once this was resolved my database cleaner was working correctly.
3. Bonus:  I didn't know, but to access @current_user amongst both scenarios I needed

   ```
   background do
     @current_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_facility)   
   end
   ```
4. I have not seen this until now, and it's great.

   ```
   2 examples, 0 failures
   ```